# Count Unique with multiple conditions in Excel

Tags: excel, unique, frequency, countif

first post, so thanks for any help.

I'm trying to write a formula which gives a count of unique matches within a range based on 4 criteria

I've searched and found some similar answers which steered me towards an formula which involved SUMPRODUCT and FREQUENCY, but I haven't been able to write the correct formula.

I have a table of records of managers assigned to an employee recorded over year and quarter.
An employee can have more than one manager within a quarter, and the same manager can be asssigned more than once within a quarter.
A manager will be recorded in a Status column as Exit, New or Change.

I have a Flag column in which I wish to look at eahc row and calculate a value based on these criteria for the row

a.  If Status = Exit, then Flag = 0
b.  If Status = Change or New, and only 1 Manager for that Employee Name in the same Q and Y, Flag = 0
c.  If Status = Change or New, and more than 1 Manager for that Employee Name  in the Same Q and Y, Flag = Count of Unique Manager names for that Employee with the same Q and Y.  [Note - it's not a count of Manager names, rather the Unique names.]

My If calculation can handle a. and b., it's c. which I am failing on.

I've attached a screenshot here. The Flag field is column F, and my formula is for the first row of data:

```
{=IF(C2 = "Exit", 0, IF(COUNTIFS($D$2:$D$9, D2, $E$2:$E$9, E2, $A$2:$A$9, A2, $C$2:$C$9, "<>Exit") = 1, "0", SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(($A$2:$A$9=A1)*($C$2:$C$9<>"Exit")*($D$2:$D$9=D1)*($E$2:$E$9=E1),$B$2:$B$9),IF(($A$2:$A$9=A1)*($C$2:$C$9<>"Exit")*($D$2:$D$9=D1)*($E$2:$E$9=E1),$B$2:$B$9))>0))))}
```

[CountUnique matches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rwIS.png)

I'm looking for a formula as a solution, so won't be doing this in a pivot table

thanks

TM

Comment: This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.* Your question may be better suited for [Super User](http://superuser.com/)